# Dynamic Memory allocation and input(stream) operator C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, allocation

I have been working on some school problem and I where I took care of memory allocation in the `operator>>`, however saw different solution, so I got bit confused over here.. The `operator>>` works good when compiled and gives good outputs, but I don't understand why, here is the code..
(Why I got confused is below the code)

```
class Some
    {
    protected:
        char *name;
        int price;
        int anything;
    public:
        Some(const char *name="", const int anything=0, const int price=0)
        {
            this->name=new char[strlen(name)+1];
            strcpy(this->name, name);
            this->anything = anything;
            this->price=price;
        }
        ~Some() { delete [] name; }
        friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, Some &i)
        {
            return in>>i.name>>i.anything>>i.price;
        }
        void print(){
           cout << name << " " << anything << " " << price; 
        }
    };
```

Main

```
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    Some n;
    cin >> n;
    n.print();
    return 0;
}
```

So with `Some n` we made an object, however the constructor has allocated memory for only 1 char, correct me if I'm wrong (and set some default values). After that we are using the `>> operator` to input an object of type `Some`, however there is only one char allocated for the `name` and we can input as much as we want.. Here is the compiled version with some input [Compiled Code](http://ideone.com/AqtwLs). Where am I wrong in my thinking ? Or this should not be done. Thanks !!

P.s we are not allowed to use libraries which will take care of the allocation ..

Comment: Your class violates the Rule Of Three.  Inputting arbitrary-length data to a char array is a hard problem...

Comment: You're right. That code is (horribly) broken.

Comment: @aschepler Yes I know, but this is just a portion of the class, because I don't want to put big blocks of code that are not connected with my question ..

Comment: @DanielJour Yeah got very confused because most of people got the same thing and I was bothered with allocating it in the input operator.. So why does this work ? Does it pull the chars from the memory because they are put like so by some coincidence ?

Comment: Stuffing more characters than what the buffer was allocated for is undefined behavior.  Plain and simple.  Your program is unstable.  Your program is also unstable if you simply did this: `{Some n; Some n2 = n;}`

Comment: Undefined Behavior can do anything, including appearing to work.

Comment: @MathNewbie *P.s we should use arrays of chars,* -- Your program doesn't use any char arrays.  A pointer to `char` is not an array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah my mistake over there just referring to the char pointer for which we later allocate memory !! Not good in terms for now ..
Thank you guys, that is the answer that I have been looking for..

Comment: If you want to actually simulate what a simple `std::string s; cin << s;` does using all of that dynamic memory allocation, [look at this Stroustrup document](http://www.stroustrup.com/new_learning.pdf).  You ready for all of that work?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes sir yes, the day is long, why not to learn something new !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Buffer Overflow (which is what you're doing, when you allocate space for a single `char`, but writing well beyond it with your call to `std::cin >> i.name`) is considered Undefined Behavior in C++. This means that compilers are allowed to do virtually anything in response to it, even stuff that seems unrelated or insane.

In practice, this means that *sometimes*, your code will work perfectly, with no problems.... until you move to a different compiler or test on a different day or had a different kind of coffee that morning, at which point the code breaks. What *should* be happening is that your code should be throwing a Segmentation Fault (or, in Windows, an Access Violation) resulting from this code, but my guess (and I want to emphasize that this is a *guess*) is that the OS level call responsible for allocating `name` is grabbing memory from early in a memory page, and your writes to unallocated memory are finding valid space in the rest of the memory page.

Obviously, you should not be relying on this kind of behavior. According to your post, you're not allowed to use an automatic memory allocation scheme like `std::vector<char>` or (the obviously correct choice) `std::string`. This is probably because your professor is <strike>an idiot that is teaching you terrible design principles because they're a senile old fool who's been out of the industry for years and hasn't caught up to how modern C++ is used and intended to be taught</strike> trying to teach you how to do manual memory allocation. <strike>For some inane reason.</strike> Therefore, you'll need to write code to handle this.

The document Paul Mckenzie linked in the comments (Also [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/new_learning.pdf)) is a good start to doing that. Page 3 is the relevant code.

Alternatively, if your professor <strike>has a sudden burst of sanity</strike> changes their mind, the corrected code would look like this:

```
class Some
{
protected:
    std::string name;
    int price;
    int anything;
public:
    //Passing by value means an optimization opportunity. We can move-construct name
    //instead of copying it.
    Some(std::string name = "", const int anything=0, const int price=0) :
    //We'll use a member-initialization list to initialize everything. Saves space
    //and saves a few CPU cycles as well!
    name(std::move(name)), anything(anything), price(price)
    {}

    //We don't need to declare the destructor anymore, because name's memory is automatically
    //managed!
    //~Some() {}

    //this code doesn't need to change.
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, Some &i)
    {
        return in >> i.name >> i.anything >> i.price;
    }

    //This doesn't technically *need* to change, but we can do better.
    //void print(){
       //cout << name << " " << anything << " " << price; 
    //}

    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, Some const& i) {
        out << i.name << ' ' << i.anything << ' ' << i.price;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the broad explanation (and the humor (which is the truth) u implemented in your answer).. I will try to understand the posted document and use string for sure !!
P.s Thanks for emphasizing that member initialization saves some cycles (been hating it all day long)

Comment: isnt `std::string` from a library and takes care of the allocation?

Comment: @MathNewbie imho learning how easy it is to use iostreams is the first thing one should learn about c++, but i am afraid your professor is so old school that he wont accept a nice solution but insist on some manual memory managment (something every sane coder tries to avoid whenever possible)

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking correctly about the problem.

The solution to the problem involves writing the length of the string to the output file and then writing the characters of the string.

Say you have object with:

```
name = "First Last"
price = 15
anything = 0
```

When the object is written, you need to have:

```
10 First Last 0 15
```

in the file.

That gives you enough information about the object to allow you read it back from the file.

```
istream &operator>>(istream &in, Some &i)
{
    size_t len;

    // Read the length of name
    in >> len;

    // Allocate memory for name.
    char* name = new char[len+1];

    // Read the name.
    // Discard the whitespace first.
    in.ignore();
    in.read(name, len);

    // Now read anything and price
    in >> i.anything >> i.price;

    // Release memory held by i.name before using memory allocated
    // in this function
    delete [] i.name;
    i.name = name;

    return in;
}
```

The function to write an object of type `Some` to a file has to mirror the function to read it back from the file.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Some const& i)
{
    out << strlen(i.name) << " ";
    out.write(i.name, strlen(i.name);
    return out << " " << i.anything << " " << i.price        
}
```

Comment: This might make the problem easier to solve without resorting to `char`-by-`char` hacks, but it's not clear from the problem description that the OP is allowed to change the format of the input data. If their program is expected to read a text file supplied by their professor, this solution won't help them.

Comment: @Xirema, that is true.